# install from remote location in ansible

Tags: linux, macos, remote-access, ansible

I am new to ansible.I am trying to fetch a setup file from a remote server and trying to copy it on my mac and then run it if necessary.Here is my playbook.[I tried get_url because i am running in a virtual box on mac.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgSOk.png).So I have ansible on my mac and linux on a virtual box on mac.So I can give commands in linux and not have to worry about mac os x syntax.So the issue i am facing is this.[This is the error ansible is showing me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFkKH.png).So please help in resolving this.Am i using the right command ,if not what can i do.

```
- name: download file  
  hosts: linux  
  user: root  
  vars_prompt:  
    - name: smb_username  
      prompt: "Enter smb share username"  
    - name: smb_password  
      prompt: "Enter smb share password"  
      private: yes  
  tasks:  
    - name: download file  
      command: smbclient "Actual url" {{ smb_password }} -U {{ smb_username }} -c "recurse;lcd /local/path;get archive.zip" creates=/local/path/archive.zip*
```

Comment: In the future, paste your code instead of using screenshots.

Comment: yeah sry about that i am new to stackoverflow as well

Comment: paste your playbook in your question.

Comment: sry formatting messed up

Comment: thanks udondan...!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a playbook, playbooks start with

`---
- hosts: 
    - hostA
  tasks:
    - name: ...
      get_url: ...`

Ansible has example playbooks, and one for get_url in particular: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/get_url.yml

Comment: yeah sry rookie stupid mistake on my end ...but even after using correct syntax its given me this error.

Comment: It won't give you a syntax error if you're using the correct syntax!  The code you have in the question currently is not correct or following the syntax given; in particular, you shouldn't have a `name` at the beginning of the block.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @XiongChiamiov!